# Angular input Error not showing when there are spaces at the front or end of name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I got a regex which will only matches the alphabets for the input. But error message is not showing when we have trailing spaces. But if we have spaces in between two words error message is visible. Here is the plunker. Please help me
[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/791RqYc6EgsW6bUfjd7P?p=preview)

```
/^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/
```

Comment: demo link is not opened

Comment: @RaviTeja It is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/791RqYc6EgsW6bUfjd7P?p=preview). And a [fixed one is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NIjg0H8JDiSxwt0fAHzr?p=preview).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks.. Just realised the ng-model is trimming trailing and leading spaces